# Webpack producing no input

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am aware that this is quite a common problem with Webpack, but I am a total newbie and the solutions I've found so far seem to be very specific to the single project. However, the scenario is the same: Webpack compiling the project correctly and then showing a blank page, without reporting any errors.

Here is my webpack.config.js (I made it following tutorials):

```
import path from 'path';  
import HtmlWebpackPlugin from 'html-webpack-plugin';

export default () => ({  
  entry: [
    path.join(__dirname, 'src/index.jsx'),
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: 'index.html',
        template: './App.html'
    }),
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        include: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel',
            options: {
              babelrc: false,
              presets: [
                ['es2015', { modules: false }],
                'react',
              ],
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(css|scss|sass)$/,
        loader: 'style!css!sass',
      },
    ]
  },
});

module.exports = config;
```

Here my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "smart-fit",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "chartjs": "^0.3.24",
    "interactjs": "^1.2.8",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "react": "^15.5.4",
    "react-dom": "^15.5.4",
    "react-hot-loader": "^3.0.0-beta.3",
    "react-table": "^5.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.4.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-register": "^6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0-beta.4",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.28.0",
    "loader-utils": "^1.1.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.2",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.3",
    "style-loader": "^0.17.0",
    "webpack": "^2.1.0-beta.25",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.1.0-beta.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Webpack version is the lastest and the project is written using React and ES5.

Comment: any error messages?

Comment: does your html load bundle.js? or 404 for the bundle file?

Comment: @ArslArsl no error messages at all. How do I see on Chrome if it loaded bundle.js?

Comment: (f12)devtools ->network tab

Comment: @ArslArsl it loads nothing.

Comment: well I should ask it first - can you find bundle.js somewhere (It should be in the same directory as webpack.config.js)?

Comment: If you're using webpack v2 like you say, then you should be using `module: { rules:...` instead of `loaders`. Check out this migration document https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/#module-loaders-is-now-module-rules

Comment: @BrettEast starting from what you linked I ended following this tutorial: http://kloc.io/setting-up-react-workflow-babel-webpack/
But the result is still the same

Comment: @ArslArsl Yes, it is regularly in the same directory.

Comment: ok you got a bundle.js - what's in your <script src="" .. in index.html - is it the correct path?

Comment: @ArslArsl it's
<script type="text/babel" src="bundle.js"></script>
the html is in the same folder of bundle.js, and they're both in the top folder

Comment: well can you remove type="text/babel" - does it help?

Comment: @ArslArsl It produces an error - the project is written in React/JSX so Babel cannot be taken off. Can it be that I wrote it using ES5 instead of ES6?

Comment: @Roc A couple of things then, how does your webpack.config file look now that you've fixed it for webpack2? Also, if you are using babel-loader, like it looks like you are, then you should also try installing `babel-preset-react`, then you can drop the `type=text/babel`. What does your bundle file look like? Is it pulling in your index.js and other files? When you inspect the bundle file in the browser, is the resource there?

Comment: @ArslArsl The webpack.config.js is now webpack.config.babel.js, and it looks like in the main question (I've updated it). Babel-preset-react was also installed when I tried to drop the "type"=text/babel".
But yes, it seems that it has not included index.jsx :/ although I've indicated it in the webpack.config

Comment: @ArslArsl The webpack.config.js is now webpack.config.babel.js, and it looks like in the main question (I've updated it). Babel-preset-react was also installed when I tried to drop the `"type"=text/babel`. But yes, it seems that it has not included `index.jsx` :/ although I've indicated it in the webpack.config